# What arcs of Shingeki No Kyojin will the live-action movie cover?

Tags: attack-on-titan

The live action movie for *Shingeki No Kyojin* is coming out in 2015 or 2016 if I am not mistaken. Does anyone know what arcs of the anime and manga the movie will cover?

Comment: I don't think any details about this have been released. In fact, I haven't even heard anything from the rumor mill.

Answer (score 8):

First off, there are a number of minor departures from the source material, such as Mikasa's general personality and the setting of the world, but this is to be expected - all adaptions have a degree of director's license, and the main bones of the series are still easily visible.

> "This is not the Attack on Titan you saw on the comic book page. This is not the Attack on Titan you saw animated on television" [...]
>
> "It takes place in the future of our world, with remnants of warplanes and weaponry peppered across the countryside. Its great walls were built by human hands..."
>
> <sub>Taken from [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/review/attack-on-titan/part-i/live-action-movie/.90469)</sub>

The first movie begins at the same point as the anime series, with the breach of the outer wall, and covers the majority of the main points up to and including the first battle in the Trost District:

- Eren, Mikasa and Armin's friendship and discussing what is outside the walls
- Eren falling out with the Garrison soldiers in his home city
- The Colossal Titan appearing and kicking a hole in the wall of the Shiganshina District (Monzen in the movie)
- Signing up to the Survey Corps. with the ideals of revenge
- Travelling to and fighting in the Trost District with the other graduated recruits from Eren's training squad (Omotemachi in the movie)
- Eren saving Armin, but being swallowed and having his arm bitten off in the process
- Eren shifting into a titan from inside the one he was eaten by, and emerging in front of Mikasa
- Eren (in Titan form) fighting the Titans inside the city
- An unconscious but fully healed Eren emerges from his defeated Titan form, signifying the end of the first movie

Additionally, a more detailed plot summary can be read [**here,**](http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_on_Titan,_The_Movie:_Part_1) along with other information on the film.

---

Therefore, the following arcs are covered in the first film:

- The 'Fall of Shiganshina' arc
- The '104th Trainees Squad' arc
- And approximately half of the 'Battle for Trost' arc

Answer (score 0):

With the second trailer of the first movie released on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2X0i4gnbBOA), and based on below synopses, it seems like the first movie will feature the first chapters of the manga. The wall will fall by the Colossal Titan, Eren will join the Survey Corpse and will have to transform to defend mankind. It is also confirmed that Levi will not feature in the movie, but an additional character and additional content will be created instead.

From [Wikia](http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_on_Titan_%28Live-Action_Movie%29):

> That day, humanity remembered... More than one hundred years ago, Titans suddenly appeared. The majority of the human race was eaten and civilization collapsed. The survivors of the war built three walls to prevent the invasion of the Titans, and kept the peace by securing the living area inside. In one hundred years, the wall has not been broken... until this day.

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2072230/):

> A teenage boy named Eren Jaeger must use his special gift to fight alongside with the military to defeat the titan race. Mankind is on the brink of extinction when these man eating monsters terrorize everybody and destroy the last of human civilization left in the world.

---

Read more on
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_on_Titan#Live-action_films), [Asianwiki](http://asianwiki.com/Attack_on_Titan_%28live-action%29), [Finalreel](http://www.finalreel.co.uk/attack-on-titan-movie-trailer-part-two-end-of-the-world/) or their [Official website](http://www.shingeki-seyo.com/).